# Требуется реализовать замену иконок элементам списка, используя jquery или js

Tags: javascript

В моём случае использованием css не обойтись. Т.к. элементы отличаются атрибутами. При наведении должна меняться иконка элемента под курсором, но почему то меняется только иконка первого элемента коллекции. Я понимаю, что ошибка именно в индексах и нужен перебор, но как реализовать не доходит.

Так же интересует, каким образом правильно выявлять элемент по его индексу?

```js
var $inserror = $('#inserror');
var $one = $inserror[0].outerHTML;
var $elem_index = $('.select_block').index();

if ($elem_index == 0) {

  $('li.select_block').hover(
    function() {
      $('#inserror').replaceWith('<i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text-danger">&#xE15D;</i>');
    },
    function() {
      $('#inserror').replaceWith($one);
    }
  );
}
});
```

```html
<li class="select_block" data-id="" onclick="">
  <i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text-'<!-- идентификатор -->'">&#xE8B2;</i>
</li>
<li class="select_block" data-id="" onclick="">
  <i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text-'<!-- идентификатор -->'">&#xE8B2;</i>
</li>
<li class="select_block" data-id="" onclick="">
  <i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text-'<!-- идентификатор -->'">&#xE8B2;</i>
</li>
<li class="select_block" data-id="" onclick="">
  <i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text-'<!-- идентификатор -->'">&#xE8B2;</i>
</li>
<li class="select_block" data-id="" onclick="">
  <i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text-'<!-- идентификатор -->'">&#xE8B2;</i>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var $inserror = $('.select_block i');
$('li.select_block').hover(
function() {
 $index = $('li').index(this);
 $one = $inserror[$index].outerHTML;
$('i', this).replaceWith('<i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text-danger">&#xE15D;</i>');},
    function() {$('i', this).replaceWith($one);})
    
    
    
// Рабочий код
$(function () {

    var $inserror = $('.select_block i');

    $('.select_block').hover(

        function() {

            $index = $('.select_block').index(this);
            $one = $inserror[$index].outerHTML;
            $('i', this).replaceWith('<i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text-danger">&#xE15D;</i>');
        },
        function() {

            $('i', this).replaceWith($one);
        })
});
```

```html
<li class="select_block" data-id="" onclick="">
  <i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text">+ иконка</i>
</li>
<li class="select_block" data-id="" onclick="">
  <i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text">иконка1</i>
</li>
<li class="select_block" data-id="" onclick="">
  <i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text">иконка2</i>
</li>
<li class="select_block" data-id="" onclick="">
  <i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text">иконка3</i>
</li>
<li class="select_block" data-id="" onclick="">
  <i id="inserror" class="md-list-addon-icon material-icons uk-text">иконка4</i>
</li>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: изображение - примеры]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: vital mar << Предложенное вами решение работает, но не совсем то что нужно. Иконка меняется при наведении на любой блок li, но при потере hover подставляется элемент i, скопированный из первого блока (с индексом 0)... Изначально все иконки у элементов разные и нужно возвращать каждому блоку именно свою. Вот тут то и "недопру" ;-) Понимаю, что нужен цикл перебора, но сам не силён в js

Comment: поправил код, посмотрите

Comment: vital mar << Вижу, что пример ваш работает, но на сайте этот кусок кода упорно не хочет работать... Chrome ругается (http://savepic.ru/13272468.png)

Comment: покажите сообщение/ошибку в консоли хрома

Comment: http://savepic.ru/13295019.png

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of undefined

Comment: Всё, немного подправил: вместо наименования эл-та класс подставил и заработало.

Спасибо ВАМ, vital mar!

Comment: Не за что, отметьте ответ как решение, может кому еще пригодиться (: